# Transposed references in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can you make excel auto fill the formulas in a transposed way? Sample:

A1:A5 some data

B1 = SomeFormulas(A1)

How to make B1:F1 = SomeFormulas(An) without adding it one by one? I mean, if you drag a cell, it will auto-fill in the same orientation, how to drag transposing the reference? It is a MUST for excel I think.

Comment: Some ppl loves the down button. I think it is a good formulate and also useful for community question.

Comment: Very useful question! (And answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

=*SomeFormulas*(INDEX($A$1:$A$5,COLUMNS($A:A)))

Copy across as required.

Regards

Comment: Please, what if I need to transpose an average of columns in rowns? Sample: Data in columns, result in rows: X1 = AVERAGE(A1:A5), X2 = AVERAGE(B1:B5)..?

Comment: In X1:  =AVERAGE(INDEX($1:$1,ROWS($1:1)):INDEX($5:$5,ROWS($1:1)))

Comment: Thank you again! Worked! Very nice! I don't know why I got a down vote.

Comment: You're welcome. And I don't either. Seemed perfectly adequately stated to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute references.

`A1` will change to B1 or A2 depending on which way you drag the cell handle.

`$A1` will keep A, but change 1.  Drag it right and it will stay A1, drag it down and it will change to A2 and so on

`A$1` will keep 1 but change A.  Drag it down and it will stay A1, drag it right and it will become B1

`$A$1` is absolute and will never change.

The **$** sign indicates that teh value after it must stay absolutely the same

Comment: I know that, but it does not apply for what I asked. If I drag it to the right, $A1 results: A1 A1 A1.... A$2 results: A2 B3 C4. What I need: A1 A2 A3!!!!